# Help setting up Bazaar Explorer between my VS2008 working directory and my dev web server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, bazaar

All I want to do is setup it up, so that after I make changes in VS2008 (local machine), I send those changes to the dev server. Also, I would like it so my other coworkers can do the same. But I don't seem to be able to get this working.

Please help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you want a shared code repository, or do you want to have the results of your build end up being served by your web server, or both?

Comment: Well I wanted both. Bazaar creating a trunk no matter what kind of repository I created was throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a repository, and a branch within it, on the central server.
2. Make a lightweight checkout of that branch on your local machine.
3. Make changes in the branch, add new files, and commit.
4. Other developers can run update to get your changes.

Now you basically have the same centralized model you would have had under svn or cvs, but with better ui and merging, and the ability to do distributed work in future.

See also http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/tutorials/centralized_workflow.html